# forEach loop not working inside nodejs db insert?

Tags: node.js

Okay so i am trying to create a mongoose insert using 2 sets of data from two variables i have set. When i try using the loop outside the db insert function it displays the data however inside the db i get the error unexpected token .forEach.

```
var storedaily = store['storefronts'][3]['catalogEntries'];
var storeweekly = store['storefronts'][5]['catalogEntries'];
  //console.log(storedaily);
  storedaily.forEach(function(key) {
    console.log(key.devName);
  });

   var insertstore = new Shop({
      storedaily.forEach(function(key) {
        itemName: key.devName
   });
 });
 insertstore.save();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the `unexpected token .forEach` error because you have it placed inside the curly braces of the `Shop` constructor, which expects an object with keys and values.

If you want to create a `Store` object with a property `items` that is an array, you could try doing something like this:

```
var insertstore = new Shop({
   items: storedaily.map(key => key.devName)
});
```

Comment: If i have multiple keys to add can i still add them dynamically? eg like a loop.